# Have a create view for related field in django restframework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

How can I have a create view for the comment in RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView of the post?
at this point, I have all the comments back in a list and can't create a single one.
I know that I can have a seperate CreateApiView for Comment model and pass the pk of the post manually. but how can I do this is post detail view? Thanks.

my post model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    body = models.TextField()
    [...]
```

my comment model:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(
        to=Post,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='comments'
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    email = models.EmailField()
    [...]
```

post detail serializer class:

```
class PostDetailSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    author = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='author.username')
    tags = TagListSerializerField()
    category = serializers.SlugRelatedField(queryset=Category.objects.all(), slug_field='name')
    comments = CommentSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = [
            'title',
            'comments',
        ]
```

and post detail view

```
class PostDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Post.published.all()
    serializer_class = PostDetailSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly]
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to create all the comments at the same time as the post? Or do you want a separate endpoint to create comments later? Consider using a viewset instead of API view and adding a custom action https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#marking-extra-actions-for-routing

Comment: No just post a comment. Thank you. I got that.